# Rails check_box stripping question mark from name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table `projects` containing a column definition `t.boolean  "active?"`.

In the associated `_form.html.erb` file I have:

```
  <tr>
    <td><%= f.label :active? %></td>
    <td><%= f.check_box(:active?) %></td>
  </tr>
```

This is generating the HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td><label for="project_active">Active?</label></td>
    <td><input name="project[active]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="project_active" name="project[active]" type="checkbox" value="1" /></td>
</tr>
```

So the parameter being passed back is `active` (no question mark), not `active?`, which promptly gets rejected by the strong parameter checking (and wouldn't match anything in the database even if it got through)

What am I doing wrong? The column was originally called `active` (no question mark), and I've changed it with a migration, but I can't find any lingering references to the old version.

Comment: you just want to check if the checkbox is active ?

Comment: No, I want to update the `active?` column in the database.

Comment: Try renaming your attribute to t.boolean `active` instead of `active?`

Answer (score 1):

Question marks (`?`) have a specific meaning in Ruby, Rails, and ActiveRecord.

Boolean attributes respond to `<attribute_name>?` as well as just `<attribute_name>` with true/false as a matter of semantic clarity. That is, the `?` makes it obvious that that attribute is a boolean and will return true or false.

Other attribute types (which are backed by columns in a database table) will respond to `<attribute_name>?`, as a shorthand for `<attribute_name>.present?`. That is, appending the `?` acts as a convenience to see if anything currently resides in the attribute.

The point being that question marks should not be part of your attribute names. A few more reasons:

- `def <atribute_name>??` is not legal (double question marks don't work in Ruby)
- Symbols cannot end in `?`
- variables cannot end in `?`
- instance variables cannot end in `?`
- `?` in method names have to be the last character. So `<my_attribute>?=` is not a valid setter method.

All of this boils down to: You should make your database column names follow the same rules as Ruby method names since ActiveRecord makes them one in the same. That is, each column name becomes an attribute with a getter and a setter. And neither the getter nor the setter nor the internal instance variable can be properly defined based on an attribute that ends in a question mark. So you'll have to change your column name back to just `active` (with no question mark).

Comment: any idea where this is documented, regarding automatic response to `?` of boolean values?

Comment: The concept is called "Attribute query methods". There's a little bit of documenation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html). Or, you can see the source [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b99a899c9a82c5ecb4ff7c8cf01b8d69ffba02b1/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/query.rb#L10).